# Private video on Vimeo

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have private videos on Vimeo and need to know if it is possible to use Vimeo's API to display them in my web app.

When my user accesses my web app, I want display my private videos without the user logging on to Vimeo.

Is it possible?

Comment: please checkout http://www.thatsupergirl.com/embedding-private-videos-with-vimeo/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it it possible. As far as I know, you have to white list the domains you want to include your videos. I do not have a paid vimeo account, but I have embedded private videos at a website.

The API documentation for vimeo is at [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api). It is actually not that bad.

To get the meta data for a certain video you can use following link (replace <id> with the video id):

```
https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/<id>
```

This can be usefull if you want to cache certain meta data at your backend side.